# How to write regex to match a key in yaml file?

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube

I have a yaml which looks like this..! Sonar by default providing sonar-yaml-plugin with some templates which accepts regex as input to verify particular key is present or not in **.yml** file.

I want regex to match entire key **logging:file**

```
 server:
   port: 8989
 logging:
    file: ./sample1.txt
    path: ./log
```

I have tried using **(logging)(?s:.*?)(file)** but its not validating when I use it in sonar-plugin.

Comment: Why don't you use a proper YAML parser ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Hi @Cid Can you please elaborate what is the need of **Yaml Parser** here ?

Comment: This is easier to use and to maintain. What if the next person who'll work on your code knows nothing about RegEx ? Althought you can find a RegEx that will match your example, I'm sure one can find many examples where this RegEx won't work, such as a commented line for file, some properties before file, the file absent, but present elsewhere ... *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."* - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @Cid you are right, but I have clearly mentioned in statement it is a plugin provided by sonar and it accepts only **regex** as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure what you may want to match, but maybe [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/ROewq5/1) might help you to do so or design your desired expression:

```
^(logging:|\s+file:)(.+)
```

[image]

- This expression has a left boundary on start <kbd>^</kbd>.
- Your two words connected with an OR (<kbd>|</kbd>)
- Then, matches everything after that using `.+`
- You can also add additional boundaries to it, however if you could add some real samples to your question, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Hi @Emma I have tried this and i am getting output what i need [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ROewq5/2). But the problem is with sonar-plugin. It is not validating the yaml file when i run sonar-scanner.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have modified your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ROewq5/3) and it works for me.